# Unreal Engine, How do I take an already completed file and put it on the oculus?

Tags: unreal-engine4, virtual-reality

I have a game that is almost completed, but I don't know how to put that file onto the oculus, so that it will ruin independently on it

Answer (score 0):

have you tried deploying your vr build on sidequest? i found this, hope its helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoOB_btt41o&ab_channel=UpsideDown
you'll need the android sdk

Comment: please add some supporting code into answer, since external links might not function in some time in future..